# Ignore case in strsplit in R

Tags: regex, r, case-sensitive, strsplit

I am aware that in [grep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) you can simply use `ignore.case = TRUE`. However, what about [strsplit](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html)? You can pass a regular expression as the second argument, but I'm not sure how I make this regular expression case insensitive.

Currently, this is what my strsplit looks like, but I want to make the search case insensitive. How would I do so?

```
strsplit(df$sentence, paste0(" ", df$node, "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"))
```

Example:

```
sentence <- "De A-bom, Sint..."; 
node <- "a-bom"

contexts <- strsplit(sentence, paste0("(?i) ", node, "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"))
(leftContext <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1))
```

Expected return:

```
[1] "De"
```

Actual return:

```
[1] "De A-bom, Sint..."
```

Note, however that the regex itself [does work online](https://regex101.com/r/zU1fE7/1).

Comment: None of the characters in the string `"( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"` depends on case.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein No, but the contents of df$node does.

Comment: @akrun I tried that, doesn't work (returns whole sentence).

Comment: A caveman solution would be to use `tolower` on `sentence` before applying the strsplit.

Comment: The example posted does not work due to the rest of the regex. Try it with the last argument of `paste0` removed, for example.

Comment: @A.Webb What do you mean, "because of the rest of the regex"? Why is that a problem?

Comment: If I've understood your problem, a similar idea to @RomanLuštrik would be to replace sentence with `gsub(node, node, sentence, ignore.case=TRUE)` which would remove the case problem for the relevant text without changing the case of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I think you have to add the `perl=TRUE` argument. This and `tolower` approach to your desired result: `strsplit(tolower(sentence), paste0("(?i) ", node, "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"),perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I might be wrong, but aren't you trying to match at word boundaries? Like [`contexts <- strsplit(sentence, paste0("(?i)[[:blank:]]*\\b", node, "\\b"))`](http://ideone.com/KiAjdz)
?

Comment: @stribizhev You're partially right. I can allow a word boundary before the node, but not after. In Dutch (the language I'm investigating) we often make compounds connected by a hyphen. I want to distinguish between my node and a compound starting with that node. E.g. the regex should match `aids` and not `aids-virus`. If I'd use word boundaries, both would be matched.

Comment: I think you can use this: [`contexts <- strsplit(sentence, "(?i) aids([] !\",.:;?})])")`](http://ideone.com/jYiBHq). The square bracket needs "smart" placement in the character class. Or use `perl=T` as A. Webb suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "(?i)" mode modifier does make PCRE based regexes case insensitive.

The problem with your example is not with case but within the grouping expression. Use `perl=TRUE` for the escaping behavior you expected.

```
sentence <- "De A-bom, Sint..."; 
node <- "a-bom"

contexts <- strsplit(sentence, paste0("(?i) ", node, 
    "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"),perl=TRUE)
(leftContext <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1))
```

Produces the expected

```
[1] "De"
```

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant! But isn't the problem now that the "array" (what's the right name again?) of punctuation isn't closed? After `|` we open with `[` and we're supposed to close with `]`, but we never do?

Comment: I still don't understand why my online RegEx does work, but it doesn't in R. https://regex101.com/r/zU1fE7/2

Comment: See edits, you need `perl=TRUE` for the escaping behavior you wanted.